# How to attach image in grid view from a folder out side the application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, radgrid

this is my rad grid column

```
<telerik:GridImageColumn HeaderText="Image" DataImageUrlFields="ContentName" DataType="System.String"
                            DataImageUrlFormatString="~/SlideImages/{0}" UniqueName="Upload" Visible="false"
                            ImageHeight="80px" ImageWidth="80px">
                            <HeaderStyle Width="10%" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        </telerik:GridImageColumn>
```

In my application i am saving image out of application folder, but at run time when the grid coulm try to attach the image through setting the out side folder path, it is unable to attach the images for the column, how to fix it?

when i set it for internal folder it works fine, as of now i have set path for application folder image. Please let me know on it.

i set the path DataImageUrlFormatString="D:\SomePath{0}" but doesnt work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a virtual directory inside your website and give path of folder that is outside your website folder and has images. Now this folder will act as it is part of your website and you will not get error. How to create Virtual Directory, [**MSDN**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/172138)

Suppose you have website folder d:\Yoursites\Testsite and you want to access files within d:\Images\first.jpg, make a virtual directory in side TestWebsite pointing to d:\images and access files within it through virual directory.

The URL for images would be something like http://yoursite.com/yourvirtualdirectoryname/first.jpg

Comment: But i a facing one more problem, now my application run after hosting to IIS, but it doest let me log in despite correct connection string..can you help me with this?

Comment: Is it related to the image path you asked in question?

Comment: Please have a glance at the thread.. i am stuck on it..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11410893/why-iis-host-application-do-not-let-log-in