# Why iis host application do not let log in?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have hosted my applciation to the IIS -7 and it browses proper but it doest let me log in now, desipte i have checked it has a correct connection string, it throws error at my log page

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

```
Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error: 


Line 96:         SqlParameter[] arrParams = new SqlParameter[0];
Line 97:         _userDetails = Data.GetSQLQueryResults(sqlQuery, 0, arrParams);
Line 98:         if (_userDetails.Rows.Count != 0)
Line 99:         {
Line 100:            _userAccountID = _userDetails.Rows[0]["UserAccountID"].ToString();


Source File: d:\Projects\June 20\CorrDefensev2\App_Code\UserInfo.cs    Line: 98 

Stack Trace: 

[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   UserInfo.setUserData(MembershipUser membershipUser) in d:\Projects\June 20\CorrDefensev2\App_Code\UserInfo.cs:98
   UserInfo..ctor(String username) in d:\Projects\June 20\CorrDefensev2\App_Code\UserInfo.cs:76
   Account_Login.Login1_LoggingIn(Object sender, LoginCancelEventArgs e) in d:\Projects\June 20\CorrDefensev2\MyPublic\Login.aspx.cs:76
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.OnLoggingIn(LoginCancelEventArgs e) +115
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.AttemptLogin() +85
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) +101
   System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +37
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.OnCommand(CommandEventArgs e) +125
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +177
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5563



the solution: all i had to use sql server authentication that is a connection string in web.config with the username, password, and it works fantastic...
```

Comment: You forgot to tell us _what_ error it throws.  And what the runtime values are when it's thrown.

Comment: When i log in with some user name , password, it throwsx error at line no 8

Comment: The error is pretty clear, `object reference not set to an instance of an object`.  Since it's happening on line 98, then either `_userDetails` or `Rows` is `null`.  My guess would be that `_userDetails` is `null`.  In which case your `Data.GetSQLQueryResults()` method is broken, since returning `null` is a bad idea.  Either way, this isn't where your problem is.  You need to fix that function (and probably a lot of other code) to report the problems it encounters so that you can determine what's wrong.

Comment: when i run it directly i mean not browsing from IIS, running form visual studio c+f5, it works fine, and also my function setUserData returns void.

Comment: `setUserData` can return whatever it wants, that's not the problem.  Running it directly or from IIS is immaterial.  `Data.GetSQLQueryResults()` is returning `null`.  Your code assumes that this method will _never_ return `null`, but it is.  You need to do some debugging to find out why it's returning `null`.  You should probably start by adding some error checking/handling to your code, as well as logging and reporting of errors and unexpected conditions.  For reasons _entirely_ outside the scope of the code you're showing, `Data.GetSQLQueryResults()` isn't doing what you assume it would.

Comment: But it runs fine in visual studio, and i am unable to attach a w3 process to debug it from IIS..and really i am deserted, i am trying for long..

Comment: You're really not listening.  The problem is entirely outside of the information you've provided in the question.  It doesn't matter that it works somewhere else under different circumstances.  It doesn't matter if you can attach a debugger to it.  Your `Data.GetSQLQueryResults()` function is returning `null` where you assume that it never will.  Either the assumption is wrong (and you need to check for a `null` value before trying to use it), or the function has a bug in it.  You need to add error trapping and logging to your application so you can see more run-time information.

Comment: do you have same database for both deployments @NoviceToDotNet

Comment: My function was absolutely correct, just i has to set the Sql server authentication in the the connection string that with a user name and password, and it got connected to the database, i was telling you that it is not getting connected to DB, you do not hear me and made 3 -ve..well thanks for your response..

Answer (score 0):

```
 SqlParameter[] arrParams = new SqlParameter[0];
 _userDetails = Data.GetSQLQueryResults(sqlQuery, 0, arrParams);
```

You are passing arrParams with zero elements in it, Your query might expect some parameter to return the result. There is a chance that you have null for _userDetails as you are getting now. You can prevent the exception by putting check for null on _userDetails

```
if (_userDetails != null && _userDetails.Rows.Count != 0)
{

}
```

To find out exact cause

```
if (_userDetails != null)
{
   //No data table returned
   if( _userDetails.Rows.Count != 0)
   {
        //No record found
   }
}
```